# how to save changes before adding new column R shiny reactive datatable

Tags: r, shiny, dt, shiny-reactivity

after editing existing cells, how do i make the cell values stay edited and not reset to original when i add a new column? tried using `reactiveValues` without success. below is the reproducible code,.

```
runApp(list(
  ui=pageWithSidebar(headerPanel("Adding entries to table"),
                     sidebarPanel(actionButton("update", "Add Column")),
                     mainPanel(DT::dataTableOutput("data"))),
  
  server=function(input, output, session) {
    df <- data.frame(Channel = c("A", "B","C"),
                     Current = c(2000, 3000, 4000),
                     Modified = c(2500, 3500,3000),
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    
    
    #smth <- reactiveValues(df2=integer(NROW(df)))
    values <- reactiveValues(df=df)
    proxyTable <<- DT::dataTableProxy("data")
    
    observeEvent(input$data_cell_edit, {
      info = input$data_cell_edit
      row = info$row
      col = info$col 
      value = info$value
      values$df[[row,col]] = value
      replaceData(proxyTable, values$df) 
    })
    
    newEntry <- observe({
      
      if(input$update > 0) {
        isolate({
          values$df[,paste0('NewCol', ncol(values$df) + 1)] <- integer(NROW(df))
        })
      }
    })
    output$data <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable({values$df}, extensions = "AutoFill", editable = 'cell',
                                                     options = list(autoFill=list(focus="click"))),server=FALSE)
  }))
```

Comment: I think you need to update the data whenever a cell is edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said you need to update the data whenever is edited, that's what this code does.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

runApp(list(
  ui=pageWithSidebar(headerPanel("Adding entries to table"),
                     sidebarPanel(actionButton("update", "Add Column")),
                     mainPanel(DT::dataTableOutput("data"))),

  server=function(input, output, session) {
    df <- data.frame(Channel = c("A", "B","C"),
                     Current = c(2000, 3000, 4000),
                     Modified = c(2500, 3500,3000),
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    
    
    smth <- reactiveValues(df2=integer(NROW(df)))
    values <- reactiveValues(df=df)
    proxyTable <<- dataTableProxy("data")

    observeEvent(input$data_cell_edit, {
      info = input$data_cell_edit
    row = info$row
    col = info$col 
    value = info$value
    values$df[[row,col]] = value
      replaceData(proxyTable, values$df) 
    })

    newEntry <- observe({
     
      if(input$update > 0) {
        isolate({
        values$df[,paste0('NewCol', ncol(values$df) + 1)] <- smth$df2
        })
      }
    })
    output$data <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable({values$df}, editable = 'cell'))
  }))
```

Comment: hello, thanks alot for your help, your code works very nicely:) just a tiny edit needed: to change "proxy" to "proxyTable" in replaceData. but i understand what's going on better now!

Comment: Oops, while I was playing about I was using some not so great variable names, e.g. i, j, v and of course proxy. Change most of them but obviously missed that one.

Comment: actually i have another question. do u know how to save edits if i enable autofill in the datatable? should have written that previously, i have edited the code in my original question.

Comment: Does the code stop working when you enable autofill?

Comment: The code still saves changes made to cells that i manually edit, but when i apply autofill to some cells with my manually edited cell's value or my original cell's value, those autofilled cell values don't get saved.

Comment: I'll see if I can come up with something, in fact I think I saw something earlier that might help with both issue.

Comment: @tycheo On [my blog](https://laustep.github.io/stlahblog/posts/DTcallbacks.html#capturing-the-autofilled-cells) I provide a way to record the changes done by autofilling.

Comment: @Stephane That's the very code I was referring to in my last comment , didn't have a chance to check it out thoroughly but I will when I get a chance.